# How to bypass the constructor value in php using inheritance?

Tags: php, inheritance

I want to create a function in a class me so I could get access of class ancestor where class ancestor is parent to class dad and class dad is parent to class me. So, I want to perform this because the functions in class ancestors are depended on the constructor value of ancestor class. And I don't want to use default constuctor of Me class and dad class for this process.

```html
class ancestor
{
var $a,$b;
public function __construct($valA,$valB)
{
    //this constructor's value i want to access
    $this->a=$valA;
    $this->b=$valB;
}
public add()
{
return($this->a+$this->b);
}

}
class dad extends ancestor
{
public function __construct()
{
//i don't want to use this as a bridge but i want to handle exception also

}

}
class me extends dad
{

public function ancestorConstructerValue($a,$b)
{
//what is the code to access the ancestor's constructor function?
}
}

$me= new me;
$me->ancestorConstructerValue("",""); //i want to enter the value through this function 
echo $me->add();
?>
```

Comment: try  $args = func_get_args();
call_user_func_array(array('parent', '__construct'), $args); in ancestorConstructerValue

Comment: i want to get access of ancestor class from me class, ancestor is not parent of me class, it's grandparent to me.

Comment: please see below code it's working properly

Comment: parent::__construct($a,$b); ?

Comment: Whilst it's not your question, you may be better off using composition for this. Have a Person class that takes one or two Person objects in their constructor that assigns to parent1 and parent2. That way, you can chain a family tree together easily. To query your ancestor, you can call `$this->parent1->getParents()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use below code : public add() should have function i.e public function add()

```
class ancestor
{
var $a,$b;
public function __construct($valA='',$valB='')
{
    //this constructor's value i want to access
    $this->a=$valA;
    $this->b=$valB;
}
public function add()
{
return($this->a+$this->b);
}

}
class dad extends ancestor
{
public function __construct()
{
//i want to use this as a bridge but i want to handle exception also
$args = func_get_args();
call_user_func_array(array('parent', '__construct'), $args); 
}

}
class me extends dad
{

public function ancestorConstructerValue($a,$b)
{
//what is the code to access the ancestor's constructor function?
$args = func_get_args();
call_user_func_array(array('parent', '__construct'), $args); 
}
}

$me= new me;
$me->ancestorConstructerValue(1,2); //i want to enter the value through this function 
echo $me->add();
```

Comment: is this possible without taking class dad's constructor? if i want to use another set constructor in class dad, would this code affect that?

Comment: nup, first try whatever your concern i.e. i mean change it acoordingly. and let me does this solved your question for adding values